# XPath: Как найти первого общего родитель двух элементов

Tags: xpath

Хочу найти первого общего родителя элементов div(Family) и input'a, не используя лестницы (/../../..).

Мой вариант `//div[contains(text(),'Family')]/ancestor::div[//input and position()=1]` работает не правильно. Какие варианты можете предложить?

На мой contains() пожалуйста не обращайте внимание.

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>Family</div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <input name='YesNo'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильным ответом для моего вопроса является следующий xpath:

`//div[text()='Family']/ancestor::div[.//input[@name='YesNo']][1]`

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте такой вариант

```
.//*[//div[.='Family'] and //input[@name='YesNo']]
```

Правда он найдет всех предков, поэтому вам надо будет либо взять первого ( `[1]`) или же последнего ( `[last()]` )

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ, он подтолкнул меня к верному решению. Мой конечный вариант можете посмотреть ниже. Спасибо, еще раз.